# Responsive CSS has effect on monitor view, but I do not want it

Tags: html, css, responsive, inverse

I try to problem make it more clear.
My problem is that my responsive CSS code works on normal site as well, not only on the mobile and etc devices. All lines closed and the @media only screen line also closed and the whole responsive css section closed with }. For some reason the resp. code overwrite the normal codes.
If I use the all @media, then nothing happened, mobile shows the site as 24" monitor. If I use the max 1000px and 800px, most of the site is working. If I use only the max 800px, then the inverse of the site is working, so the elements working exactly the opposite way between the max 1000px and 800px comb and only 800px setting. Absolutely crazy... Some sizing does not work on mobile, but colors can be changed.

```
<div class="foentry">

<div class="fo1bal">

<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/kis-keep-it-simple/images/d42.png" border="0" alt="">

</div>



<div class="fo1koz">

<h2>Rólunk</h2>

<center>Üdvözlünk mindenkit!</center><br>
Üzletünkben különleges Muffinok találhatóak, kicsiknek és nagyoknak egyaránt. Térjenek be hozzánk és kóstolják meg termékeinket, melyeket Glutén, Laktóz és Cukormentes változatban is kérhetik.


</div>


<div class="fo1jobb">

<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/kis-keep-it-simple/images/767.png" border="0" alt="">

</div>


</div>




<div class="foentry2">

<h2>Muffinjaink</h2>



<div class="fo21">

<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/kis-keep-it-simple/images/kakaos-tejcsokis.png" border="0" alt="">
<center><h4>Kakaós tejcsokis</h4></center>

</div>



<div class="fo21">

<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/kis-keep-it-simple/images/turorudi.png" border="0" alt="">
<center><h4>Túrórudis</h4></center>

</div>

<div class="fo21">
<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/kis-keep-it-simple/images/franciareggeli.png" border="0" alt="">
<center><h4>Francia reggeli</h4></center>
</div>


<div class="catgomb">
<a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>category/muffinok/">Összes Muffin</a>
</div>


</div>





<div class="foentry2a">
<h2>Kávék</h2>

<div class="fo21">
<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/kis-keep-it-simple/images/cappuchino.png" border="0" alt="">
<center><h4>Cappucino</h4></center>
</div>

<div class="fo21">
<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/kis-keep-it-simple/images/coffee.png" border="0" alt="">
<center><h4>Kávé</h4></center>
</div>

<div class="fo21">
<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/kis-keep-it-simple/images/latte.png" border="0" alt="">
<center><h4>Latte</h4></center>
</div>


</div>




<div class="foentry2b">
<h2>Alkoholmentes koktélok</h2>

<div class="fo21">
<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/kis-keep-it-simple/images/batman.png" border="0" alt="">
<center><h4>Batman</h4></center>
</div>

<div class="fo21">
<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/kis-keep-it-simple/images/mickey.png" border="0" alt="">
<center><h4>Minnie Mouse</h4></center>
</div>

<div class="fo21">
<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>/wp-content/themes/kis-keep-it-simple/images/tarzan.png" border="0" alt="">
<center><h4>Tarzan</h4></center>
</div>


<div class="catgomb">
<a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>category/koktelok/">Összes Koktél</a>
</div>



</div>







<div class="foentry3">

<h2>Akciók és kedvezmények</h2>


<div class="fo31">
<h3>Akció 1.</h3>

<ul>
    <li>2db puncsos muffin</li>
    <li class="utso">1db 0,25l Cappy</li>
</ul>

<h4>900 Ft</h4>
</div>



<div class="fo31">
<h3>Akció 2.</h3>

<ul>
    <li>1db kávés+1db mákos almás muffin</li>
    <li class="utso">1db 0,25l szénsavas üdítő</li>
</ul>

<h4>900 Ft</h4>
</div>



<div class="fo31">
<h3>Akció 3.</h3>

<ul>
    <li>2db diós muffin</li>
    <li class="utso">3dl limonádé</li>
</ul>

<h4>850 Ft</h4>
</div>

<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="fo31">
<h3>Akció 4.</h3>

<ul>
    <li>2db válaszható muffin</li>
    <li class="utso">Cappucino</li>
</ul>

<h4>750 Ft</h4>
</div>



<div class="fo31">
<h3>Felnőtt akció 1.</h3>

<ul>
    <li>1db válaszható muffin</li>
    <li class="utso">Hosszú kávé</li>
</ul>

<h4>700 Ft</h4>
</div>



<div class="fo31">
<h3>Felnőtt akció 2.</h3>

<ul>
    <li>1db kávés muffin</li>
    <li class="utso">Latte</li>
</ul>

<h4>750 Ft</h4>
</div>


</div>
```

Resp. CSS:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {



html{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#navigation{
margin:0;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
float:left;
display:block;
height:5%;
}

#navigation a{
font-size:3.5vw;
}

#header0 .blog-info { 
position:absolute;
width:26%;
margin-left:38%;
margin-top:6%;
float:left; 
}

.blog-info img{
width:100%;
}

.m1{
position:absolute;
float:left;
margin:0 0 0 5%;
padding:0 0 0 0;
}

.m2{
position:absolute;
float:left;
margin:0 0 0 27%;
padding:0 0 0 0;
}

.m3{
float:right;
position:absolute;
margin:0 0 0 54%;
padding:0 0 0 0;
}

.m4{
float:right;
position:absolute;
margin:0 0 0 73%;
padding:0 0 0 0;
}

.fo1bal{
width:100%;
float:left;
}

.fo1koz{
width:90%;
padding:0 5%;
float:left;
font-size:3.3vw;
line-height:1.6em;
}


.fo1koz h2{
margin:10% 0 12% 0;
font-size:4.8vw;
}

.fo1jobb{
width:100%;
float:left;
}

.foentry2
width:100%;
float:left;
}

.foentry2 h2{
margin:10% 0 12% 0;
font-size:4.5vh;
}

.fo21{
width:90%;
padding:0 5%;
margin-bottom:12vh;
}

.fo21 h4{
font-size:3vh;
margin:3vh 0 0 0;
}


.foentry2a h2{
margin:10% 0 12% 0;
font-size:4.5vh;
}

.foentry2b h2{
margin:10% 0 12% 0;
font-size:4.5vh;
line-height:1.5em;
}






}
```

@Admin, please tell me if I have to share more details before closing the question. I really need to solve this.
Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Is this all your CSS or there is more to it?

Comment: `.foentry2` on line 87 has a missing `{`

Comment: Thank you. I checked million times. I kill myself. Thank you really.

Comment: Suggestion : add a language identifier to highlight the css and make it more readable.